# how to stay in current page after Updating datatable DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am working with data table , every thing is fine but now i need to stay on current page after updating and refresh page. Currently it comes in  first page after update. I am using Data-table DOM.

```
      $("#dataTable").dataTable({
            "order": [],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets"  : 4,
                "orderable": false,

            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Happy Coding :)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
});
```